# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.spout.MultiScheme.deserialize([B)Ljava/lang/Iterable;

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using storm:0.9.7 , scala-library:2.11.7 ,kafka-clients:0.9.0.0 , kafka : kafka_2.11

RuntimeError:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.spout.MultiScheme.deserialize([B)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
        at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.generateTuples(KafkaUtils.java:209) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:131) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:141) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.aexp.fastdata.core.builder.spout.KafkaExtractorSpout.nextTuple(KafkaExtractorSpout.java:112) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4615$fn__4630$fn__4661.invoke(executor.clj:610) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-mapr-1611.jar:0.10.0-mapr-1611]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0-mapr-1611.jar:0.10.0-mapr-1611]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your environment, how you're running the code, etc.? I'm thinking there may be an issue with an outdated or conflicting dependency or you may just be missing something. But I can't rule any of that out with just the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the following dependency in your build
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.7"